# Get child node from JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have a json came from an API. I need help on how to get the child node `"id"`?

Example JSON:

```
"main_address": {
        "id": "6127bff9023d4f92b9ceddf36d93287c",
        "displayed_as": "19street\nLA US-CA 90210",
        "$path": "/addresses/6127bff9023d4f92b9ceddf36d93287c"
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible, that you get a parse error? In that case, try to add { to the begin and } to the end, to make your sample a valid json object.

Comment: Show what you have tried, this isn't a programming service.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using 2 methods:

- Using JObject.Parse() method,
- Creating a model structure as per the JSON structure.

But for both the method first you need to deserialize the JSON that you wanted to parse. 
You can get more details [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-json-string-in-C-Sharp/) you will get a better idea about this.